# Remove <p><br/></p> with DOMxpath or regex?

Tags: php, regex, xpath, domxpath

I use DOMxpath to remove html tags that have empty text node but to keep `<br/>` tags,

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

while(($nodeList = $xpath->query('//*[not(text()) and not(node()) and not(self::br)]')) && $nodeList->length > 0) 
{
    foreach ($nodeList as $node) 
    {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
}
```

it works perfectly until I came across another problem,

```
$content = '<p><br/><br/><br/><br/></p>';
```

How do remove this kind of messy `<br/>`and`<p>`? which means I don't want to allow `<br/>` alone with `<p>` but I allow `<br/>` with proper text like this only,

```
$content = '<p>first break <br/> second break <br/> the last line</p>';
```

Is that possible?

Or is it better with a regular expression?

I tried something like this,

```
$nodeList = $xpath->query("//p[text()=<br\s*\/?>\s*]");
    foreach($nodeList as $node) 
    {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
```

but it return this error,

```
Warning: DOMXPath::query() [domxpath.query]: Invalid expression in...
```

Comment: What happens to `<p><br/>hello</p>` and `<p>hello<br/></p>`? And can you provide more test cases? I seem to have a little solution but not sure if it satisfies all cases.

Comment: good question! I have just thought of that! ideally, I would like to remove the `<br/>` if no text before or after it. Is it possible? Please have a look on my new post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844646/how-can-i-remove-br-if-no-text-comes-before-or-after-it-domxpath-or-regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the unwanted p using XPath:

```
"//p[count(*)=count(br) and br and normalize-space(.)='']"
```

---

**Note** to select empty-text nodes shouldn't you better use (?):

```
"//*[normalize-space(.)='' and not(self::br)]"
```

This will select any element (but br) whithout text nodes, nodes like:

```
<p><b/><i/></p>
```

or

```
<p> <br/>   <br/>
</p>
```

included.

Answer (score 1):

You could get rid of them all by simply checking to see that the only things within a paragraph are spaces and `<br />` tags: `preg_replace("\<p\>(\s|\<br\s*\/\>)*\<\/p\>","",$content);`

Broken down:

```
\<p\>    # Match for <p>
(        # Beginning of a group
  \s       # Match a space character
  |        # or...
  \<br\s*\/\> # match a <br /> tag, with any number (including 0) spaces between the <br and />
)*       # Match this whole group (spaces or <br /> tags) 0 or more times.
\<\/p\>  # Match for </p>
```

I will mention, however, that unless your HTML is well-formatted (one-line, no strange spaces or paragraph classes, etc), you should not use regex to parse this. If it is, this regex should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have almost same situation, i use:

```
$document->loadHTML(str_replace('<br>', urlencode('<br>'), $string_or_file));
```

And use `urlencode()` to change it back for display or inserting to database.
Its work for me.