# How can I remove <br/> if no text comes before or after it? DOMxpath or regex?

Tags: php, html, regex, xpath, domxpath

How can I remove `<br/>` if no text comes before or after it?

For instance,

```
<p><br/>hello</p>
<p>hello<br/></p>
```

they should be rewritten like this,

```
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
```

Should I use DOMxpath or regex would be better?

(Note: I have a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837892/remove-pbr-p-with-domxpath-or-regex) about removing `<p><br/></p>` with DOMxpath earlier, and then I came across this issue!)

**EDIT:**

If I have this in the input,

```
$content = '<p><br/>hello<br/>hello<br/></p>';
```

then it should be

```
<p>hello<br/>hello</p>'
```

Comment: What if you have something like `<p>hello<br><i>world</i></p>`? You want to remove the `<br/>` in that case?

Comment: @netcoder, thanks for pointing it out - keep it in that case :-)

Comment: Let me understand what you want to achieve and I'll post my 2 cents.

Comment: Hope you don't have situation like `<br/><br/>`.

Comment: yes I have the situation like `<br/><br/>`...  and I use `pre_replace` to solve this situation - `$content = preg_replace('/(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/', '<br/>', $content);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select the mentioned br you can use:

```
 "//p[node()[1][self::br]]/br[1] | //p[node()[last()][self::br]]/br[last()]"
```

or, (maybe) faster:

```
 "//p[br]/node()[self::br and (position()=1 or position()=last())]"
```

Just getting the br when the first (or last) node of p is br.

This will select br such as:

```
<p><br/>hello</p>
<p>hello<br/></p>
```

and first and last br like in:

```
<p><br/>hello<br/>hello<br/></p>
```

not middle br like in:

```
<p>hello<br/>hello</p>
```

---

PS: to get eventually the first br in a pair like this `<br/><br/>`:

```
"//br[following::node()[1][self::br]]"
```

Comment: Thanks empo! I have an issue with `'<p><br/>hello<br/>hello<br/></p>'` - please have a look on my edit above. Thanks!

Comment: updated with good alternative, and bonus for br pairs. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In case for some code, I could get it to working like this ([Demo](http://codepad.org/d5IohsjR)). It has a slight modification from @empo's xpath (very slightly) and shows the removal of the matches as well as some more test-cases:

```
$html = <<<EOD
<p><br/>hello</p>
<p>hello<br/></p>
<p>hello<br/>Chello</p>
<p>hello <i>molly</i><br/></p>
<p>okidoki</p>
EOD;

$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//p[node()[1][self::br] or node()[last()][self::br]]/br');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
var_dump($doc->saveHTML());
```